# Safari (Windows and Mac) Grid bug on re-sizing the window - bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting this weird type of bug with using the grid layout of BootStrap 3.

Before resizing the window:
[image: Before Resizing the window]

After you resize the window:
[image: After Resizing the window]

Again, resizing back to normal:
[image]

You can check out it by yourself http://b.nitroxis.me/restaurant/detail.html while you re-size it, the grid disturbs but when I reload it again it becomes normal again. The bug is just occurring in Safari 5.1.7 on both windows and Mac

Comment: Here is the issue ever knew in bootstrap : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9774

Comment: `display: inline` seems to fix it, no ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn On which class ?

Comment: on `.nav-tabs.nav-justified` with a breakpoint !

Comment: I have tried by making it display: inline. Doesn't fixed the issue either.

Comment: @TheLittlePig Is there any workaround for this bug? Client is really desperate about this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very sorry for you...

As you can read in the **official doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified

**Extract** :

> **Safari and responsive justified navs** 
>   As of v7.0.1, Safari exhibits a
>   bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering
>   errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing. This bug
>   is also shown in the justified nav example.

And with this **official exemple** : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

---

### There is no workaround...   ;-(

---

Comment: I removed the bootstrap classes and coded the style for this section by myself.

Comment: I think it's the better thing to do in waiting for a possible update from twbs...